# PHP how to increase session.gc_maxlifetime? changing php.ini doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, settings, php-7, ini

Running PHP7 in Apache on Ubuntu 18.04. I want to increase the default `session.gc_maxlifetime` from 1440 seconds to 86400 (a day).

`phpinfo()` shows the php.ini file being loaded is: `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`

I edit this file, change this line:

`session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440`
from 1440 to 86400.

This is the only occurrence of `gc_maxlifetime` in the php.ini file.

Afterwards I restart Apache, and check `phpinfo()` again.

`session.gc_maxlifetime` is still 1440

Is there a way to find out exactly how or where PHP gets its gc_maxlifetime setting from? Or how do I permanently, globally, change the gc_maxlifetime to 86400 seconds?

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same issue with AWS bitnami php. What's wrong here? My php version is 7.3.11.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found out how to apply the php.ini.

The root cause was that below command doesn't reload the php.ini.

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

Since I'm using AWS lightsail I connected AWS lightsail console.

[image]

1. First of all stop the instance here.

[image]

2. And when the instance is completely stopped tap the start button.
   (It's worth to note that.. the restart or reboot button doesn't trigger complete reboot. So you should tap the stop button and then start button)

[image]
3. Check `session.gc_maxlifetime` through phpinfo().

PS.
Anyways it's my first time that `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache` doesn't working.
In addition I found out that `php -r 'echo ini_get("session.gc_maxlifetime"), "\n";'` command just read current php.ini file and it doesn't mean server's current settings. It seems it is best to use phpinfo() to check the server's current setting values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart the php-fpm service.

```
$ sudo systemctl stop php5-fpm.service
$ sudo systemctl start php7.0-fpm.service
```